# Return model relation / pivot in a method after creation in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I return the model with his relation / pivot in a method after a `firstOrNew`?

Model:

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';

```
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';

public $timestamps = true;


protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'address',
    'city',
    'county',
    'country',
    'phone',
    'organization_id',
    'unique_value'
  ];

protected $guarded = [];

public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\CustomerLocations', 'customer_customer_locations', 'customer_id', 'address_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

}

Method:

```
$customer = Customer::firstOrNew(['unique_value' => $unique_code]);
```

Do some logic...
and

```
return $customer;
```

How can I return the `$customer` with `locations()`?? I will do a `firstOrNew` for locations too.

Comment: if you want to have it all the time then add this line to your `Customer ` model: `protected $with = ['locations'];`, if you want to have it on the fly then simply do this: `$customer->load('locations')` or `$customer->with('locations)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use     `protected $appends = ['locations'];` in your Model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';

public $timestamps = true;

protected $appends = ['locations'];



protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'address',
    'city',
    'county',
    'country',
    'phone',
    'organization_id',
    'unique_value'
  ];

protected $guarded = [];

public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\CustomerLocations', 'customer_customer_locations', 'customer_id', 'address_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Or you use `return $cusotmer->load(['locations'])`